# How do I listen to music on my computer through my iPad?

Tags: ios, music

I have a MacMini with my music collection on the hard drive.  I'd like to play that through my iPad when I'm at home.  But I have one major issue: **I'm on satellite internet with a limited bandwidth.**  One month I got hit with an extra $200 bill because I left iTunes running and it wasted gigabytes of bandwidth "updating" the music on my iMac from the iCloud.  (I don't store my music on my iMac - it's all on a shared drive on my MacMini.)

So I don't want to go through iTunes to do this (and, after that experience, I never run iTunes on my iMac or MacMinis), since that means I'm streaming my collection from the iCloud servers and using bandwidth.

I want to be able to make up playlists on my iPad (I'm okay with a 3rd party app) of the music files on the shared drive of my MacMini and play it back through my iPad, using wifi, but not using any internet bandwidth.

How can I make up playlists on my iPad for music on a shared drive on my LAN so I can use the playlists like I would normally use them?  (In other words, being able to pick out a playlist, shuffle play it, repeat it, and so on.)

Comment: I'll also add, in case it comes up, that I've tried to use VLC, but it simply will not log into my MacMini and read the shared volumes (and I do have SMB on in my sharing for the necessary folder).  I've tried using the server name and the server IP address, logging in as a guest and under my username.  I've tried everything in multiple combinations and VLC just won't log in!

Comment: iTunes does not stream from servers unless you tell it to - I think the thing which does is Apple Music and you need to pay for that. I just buy downloads from iTunes store and buy CDs - no streaming from the internet

Comment: iTunes on the Mac, and Music on iOS, will stream in the following cases: you have purchased music from the iTunes Store but not downloaded it; you have subscribed to iTunes Match and play a track with is Matched or Uploaded but not downloaded to the device; or you have subscribed to Apple Music and play a track which is not downloaded. @Tango can you clarify whether you have iTunes Match and/or Apple Music?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few possible solutions:

### [Plex](https://www.plex.tv/)

I haven't used this but it appears to do exactly what you ask for. Install the free server on the Mac and the (paid) app on the iPad. You don't need to sign up for a subscription and it says you don't even need to sign in to stream from a local server, which should help assure you that no streaming from the internet will take place.

### Rogue Amoeba's [Airfoil](https://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/)

Install **Airfoil for Mac** on the Mac Mini where your music is and **Airfoil Satellite for iOS** on the iPad.

Airfoil is not free, but you can try it before you buy and it should work reliably and is well supported. It routes **any audio source(s) you choose on the Mac** to play simultaneously on one or more compatible destinations - so you can use any Mac audio player you like, including but not limited to iTunes. Airfoil Satellite has basic remote control capabilities for some applications such as iTunes and Spotify, but you would need something else to create and edit playlists - I'm pretty sure Apple's **iTunes Remote** can do this, for example, or if you use VLC on the Mac there's [VLC Mobile Remote](https://vlcmobileremote.com/) for the iPad.

### [Logitech Media Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logitech_Media_Server)

The server you run on the Mac is free, on the iPad you would need the [SqueezePad](http://squeezepad.com/) client app (paid).

### DLNA

Install a UPnP/DLNA media server such as [Kodi](https://kodi.tv/about) (free) on the Mac and use a DLNA client app for iOS - I don't know which to recommend, but there are [lots to choose from](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=dlna+ios+app) including some free ones.

### iTunes

You say you don't want to use iTunes and iOS Music because of the risk of it using too much data. I'm not sure whether you're talking about iTunes on the Mac Mini downloading purchased or matched (if you have iTunes Match) tracks, or Music on the iPad streaming these tracks or playing from Apple Music (if you have Apple Music), but there are two ways you should be able to use Music on the iPad without this happening:

- Sync the music from iTunes on the Mac to the iPad via USB. You will need enough storage on the iPad to fit it! In **Music** on the iPad, make sure you only play from within the **Downloaded Music** section of your library.
- Turn on [Home Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202190) on iTunes and only play from within the **Home Sharing** section of your library. I (and others) have never found Home Sharing to work reliably but feel free to try it.

The only problem with these two is if you accidentally play music from outside the Home Sharing or Downloaded sections of the library.

### Block streaming traffic on your router

A final suggestion, depending on what router and/or other equipment for the satellite internet connection you have: is there a setting you can make to block or throttle streaming audio traffic, and/or iTunes downloads? I don't know what servers, protocols or ports you would need to block but you might be able to get that answered with another question here.

Comment: You're talking about using iTunes.  So do I need Airfoil Satellite on my iPad if I'm going to use iTunes?

Comment: Sorry, I missed where you said you didn't want to use iTunes. You can use any audio player you like on the Mac but iTunes is probably the easiest to control from Satellite. I think you should be able to set up iTunes so that it doesn't send or receive anything to/from the internet. You can probably even do the same with Spotify which can also be controlled from Satellite to some extent (last time I checked the Spotify app on Mac could discover and play local audio as well as streaming from Spotify itself). If you find another audio player with an iOS remote-control app, you can use that.

Comment: I can use iTunes on the iPad, as long as I'm going through my LAN and connecting with my MacMini that way, instead of using iTunes to play my music through Apple's normal procedure (streaming it from iCloud servers).

So are you talking about using Satellite to control iTunes, or to use iTunes and have it take input from Satellite?

Comment: Sounds like I still haven't explained it well, sorry! Please see my edit. When you say 'iTunes on the iPad' I assume you mean the Music app, or are you on quite an old version of iOS?

Comment: Okay.  I tried Plex, but the first thing it did was force me to set up an account and it wouldn't do a thing without me doing that.  That's a concern for me because it means it stays in contact with their server and I have no idea how much data it sends back and forth, so I skipped that.  I tried Kodi, but this is running on my MacMini, which I control through Screen Sharing.  Kodi does something obnoxious with the pointer.  The first thing it wanted me to do is tell it what the share directory is.  5 minutes later, due to the pointer issue, I was still trying to set it up. (See next comment.)

Comment: I used to have Squeezeboxes - back before Logitech jumped in and made them worthless.  The short version is I ended up using Universal Media Server.  It seems to be working just fine.  Your point about DLNA was the biggest help.  When I found issues with Kodi and the others, I searched for DLNA and that's how I found UMS.  I ended up trying the free versions of several players on iOS and ended up using 8Player.  (I thought MLPlayer would work, but it brought up it's screen and wouldn't do a thing after that!)  Home Sharing was also something else that didn't work at all.  (See next...)

Comment: I set up Home Sharing on iTunes on the MacMini and my iPhone and iPad.  It saw my music collection, but all it had was generic playlists (like Most Recently Played and Top 25 Played).  It also had a "90s Music" playlist - one I have not created!  But it had NO music tracks on it.  That was weird!  It was a REAL frustrating afternoon, since so many programs didn't work for one reason or another.  While I didn't use the exact programs you suggested, you pointed me in the right direction and your suggestion of checking DLNA programs was what did it in the long run.  Thank you!

Comment: And thanks - for some reason I had just not thought of throttling iTunes and that's a good idea!

Comment: @Tango could you please provide your solution? That makes it easier for other curious visitors of your question to find a solution for a compareable issue...

Comment: @pallox: I'm still testing it.  For now I'm using Universal Media Server as the server on my MacMini and I'm using 8Player (or is it Player8) on my iPhone and iPad.  I have not had time to see how well UMS handles video at this point.  I know, though, it works for this single use.  (I'm using a bluetooth sleep mask so I can fall asleep to music or old time radio shows.  I made a playlist of tracks on my hard drive (streamed by UMS) and I'm playing it through my iPhone with 8Player.

Answer (score 2):

I do this using iTunes (I do not have apple music so there is no syncing to the cloud)

In iTunes on the Mac or pc turn on sharing in Preferences -> sharing -> Share library on my local network.  (So the option for sharing will not use the cloud)

On your iPad go to Settings->Music At the bottom is Home sharing - you need the same Apple Id that you use in iTunes (which does not have to be the same as that for iCloud)

On the ipad the mac's play lists appear in the submenu shared libraries at the bottom of the iPad library entries  and choose the name of the shared library.

See Apple's documentation https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202190

Comment: I never knew iTunes could do anything like this.  But, for some reason, it gives me a few play lists (like last 25 played) and that includes a playlist or two that are not mine.  (Maybe generic titles?)  But not one of my own playlists or music tracks show up.

Comment: If the playlists are there on the Mac, I think you should be able to see them in the Home Sharing library on the iOS device. But I've never found Home Sharing to be usable, frankly - for me it always takes ages trying to read the library before giving up and showing a small fraction of the content that should be there.

Answer (score 1):

That's only a suggestion, but have a look at [MusicStreamer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/musicstreamer/id979888370). There may be alternatives to that app, but that's pretty much what you are looking for, I think.